# API PLATFORM 3.1 : creating custom filter with DTO and POST request

Tags: symfony6

I need to create custom POST request using DTO and Paginator with API PLATFORM v3.1 which will be  querying on  multiple tables .
I didn't find anything on the official website.
Is it better to use a custom Controller or Processor ?

Best regards.